# Unidirectional @OneToMany creates unique index at jon table which is not expected

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm puzzled with JPA behaviour. Underlying DB is H2, I'm using SpringBoot and

```yaml
jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Here is my entity:

```scala
@Entity
class ChildEntity{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  var id: Long = _


  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  var parentEntities: java.util.Set[ParentEntity] = _
}
```

Here is what's created in DB:

```sql
CREATE INDEX "PUBLIC"."INDEX_C" ON "PUBLIC"."CHILD_ENTITY_PARENT_ENTITIES"("CHILD_ENTITY_ID");

CREATE PRIMARY KEY "PUBLIC"."PRIMARY_KEY_CA" ON "PUBLIC"."CHILD_ENTITY_PARENT_ENTITIES"("CHILD_ENTITY_ID", "PARENT_ENTITIES_ID");

-- why?
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PUBLIC"."UK_INDEX_C" ON "PUBLIC"."CHILD_ENTITY_PARENT_ENTITIES"("PARENT_ENTITIES_ID");
```

Why does it create unique index for `PARENT_ENTITIES_ID` on join table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jpa create join table automatically.

You can avoid extra join table issue using @JoinColumn .
The @JoinColumn annotation helps Hibernate  to figure out that there is a Foreign Key column in parent.

Answer (score 1):

This is to be expected, a one to many relationship connects two different entities together. JPA by default implements this when you don't do it explicitly. That is why you have a join table with the id for both entities.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible to tell JPA not to create unique index for `PARENT_ENTITIES_ID `? Primary key constraint is enough.

Comment: Primary key is here compound of parent and child id.

Comment: Composite primary key is expected. `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PUBLIC"."UK_INDEX_C" ON "PUBLIC"."CHILD_ENTITY_PARENT_ENTITIES"("PARENT_ENTITIES_ID");  ` unique index on parentEntity is unexpected

Comment: @Capacytron it's unique because for a `ParentEntity` entity you can't use multiple `ChildEntity` as you defined your relation.